# android-apt & jack and jill

Tags: android, java-8, android-jack-and-jill, android-apt

**Android Studio 2.2**

**Gradle Android Tools 2.2.0**

**Gradle Wrapper 2.14.1-all**

I am using apt plugin to compile ButterKnife ( version 8.2.1 ) library and I want to use lambda with jack and jill support.

**android apt plugin**

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

**android apt classpath**

```
classpath "com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8"
```

if I am trying to enable jack toolchain

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    // java 8 language support
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

jack and apt together gives following error :

```
Error:Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.
```

if I am removing android-apt plugin, jack toolchain works great. so, what should we do to use these together ?

Comment: Why are you using Jack over Retrolambda? Just curious

Comment: Retrolambda has issue with Proguard. Retrolambda wiki says " use -dontwarn java.lang.invoke.* with proguard". but if you use this with proguard and you decompile result apk, you will see there is no obfuscation in code. so, this is why I am not using retrolambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`android-apt` does not support Jack. As of the Android Gradle plugin version 2.2 I recommend to switch to the built in annotation support that also supports Jack. [See this short guide on how to migrate from android-apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration).

Comment: I will write result after I try it. thanks for the official link.

Comment: I tried and solved the problem. thanks for the migration link !